# Add second IP block to one debian box (one nic) from different subnet than the first block

Tags: debian, virtualization, linux-networking

I have the following:

xxx.xxx.199.208/29
xxx.xxx.221.64/27

The /29 IP block is available directly from the network drop
The /27 IP block is statically routed to xxx.xxx.199.210 of the /29

Here's how eth0 is configured:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address xxx.xxx.199.210
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway xxx.xxx.199.209
broadcast xxx.xxx.199.215
network xxx.xxx.199.208
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

So, basically there's no problem with /29 block, but I don't get the /27 block to se the light. I have enabled net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 on sysctl, have created routes, vlans, interfaces aliases, but I'm basically just fishing from what I have found around. No luck. Although i got the feeling I'm pretty close and there's only a tiny step missing.

The box is a hardware node, so the /27 block will be used to assign IPs to openvz containers. So I need to setup this the most efficient and secured way, maybe I'm letting my mind wander and there's nothing to worry about efficiency or security.

This is what command route -n outputs:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
xxx.xxx.221.65   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 venet0
xxx.xxx.199.208  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         xxx.xxx.199.209  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

There's one container running as you can see on the first route, I can ping it from the HN and viceversa, but I can't ping anything else from the container to the outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional virtual network interfaces in Linux using formatting as such:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
ifconfig eth0:1 10.11.12.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
ifconfig eth0:2 192.168.128.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

All three IP addresses will be active on the same physical interface, each will be visible in an `ifconfig` listing and the appropriate actions will happen just as though they were different interfaces.

Hopefully that covers what you need to know.

Comment: Virtual interfaces are deprecated, the correct way to add additional IPs is with the `ip` tool.

Comment: I have done it before, but no luck. Somebody told me that even with the virtual interfaces I would need to route the new subnet